# How to create a fluorescent fluid material?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders, lighting

Does anyone know how to create a material similar to the fluorescent green fluid found in this image?

[image]
Credit: Anton Lavrushkin

Comment: IMHO it's yellow, not green.

Comment: I apologize, I have a mild color blindness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

[image: Fluorescent Material]

and what it looks like if it's the only source

[image: Glow Stick]

To get precisely the look you want, play with the strength of the emission node and the Blend value of the Layer Weight node.

Basically this makes the material transparent in the center and gradually more emissive as you approach the edges, as viewed from the camera.

It's common to put a black and white color ramp between the Layer Weight and the Mix shader to give even more control over the mixing effect.

Answer (score 3):

Since the reference image is glowing in places construction around the tube ... Marty's material can be enhanced by AO (**Ambient Occlusion**) factor to fake this part of light effect.

[image]
[image]